# Accidentally deleted a partition, does anyone know what I deleted?

Tags: partitioning

i deleted a partition accidetally, thinking I was on my USB drive.

It is a lenovo laptop that has 20.04 desktop. I have EFI System 538MB FAT, Free space 4.5GB (the one I think I deleted) , and File system partition 3 Ext 4:

[image: Picture of my partitions here]

Does anyone know what I deleted in the 4.5GB free space? and how I can get it back?

Comment: Does the system start up and run more or less normally, if a bit slowly when you load more than one application?

Comment: I rebooted and it loaded up fine. I just have no idea what I deleted which is worrying because the laptop is straight from the factory. I was thinking swap or a recovery partition?

Comment: It is probably a utility partition. Most OEM manufacturers include one. You should try a tool like `testdisk` to recover it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your system a) is not a dual boot, and b) starts and runs apparently normally, I think it's most likely that you accidentally deleted your swap partition.

Sometimes, doing this will cause the system to crash (due to being memory-bound), but if you don't put a lot of demand on the system and/or you have adequate physical RAM, your computer may appear to run normally.

To correct this, you'll need to recreate a swap partition in the empty space -- that's easy using any disk manager (my own preference is Gparted, but there are lots of options).  The more complex part is you'll need to tell Ubuntu to use this new swap-format partition for actual swap activity.

I'm used to doing this by editing `/etc/fstab` -- you'd open it with root privilege in your preferred text editor (I use Kate on Kubuntu, used to use Pluma when I ran Mate), locate the line that shows partition type "swap" and change its UUID to that of the newly created swap partition (your disk utility will show the UUID of partitions under "Properties") -- WITHOUT MAKING ANY OTHER CHANGES to this file.  Save the file, exit, and reboot, and Ubuntu will run with correct swap activity.

Comment: I wouldn't assume it was a swap partition (which aren't used much anymore anyway). Given the size and location it is far more likely to be a utility partition for running diagnostics and such.